# Ubuntu completely freezes once in a while

Tags: log

I used to have the same problem with Ubuntu 16.04. Recently, I have done a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04, but still have the same problem. When it happens, keyboard doesn't work, either, and I cannot switch to any tty, or restart the PC, so I should do a cold restart.

My machine is a dual boot, Ubuntu and Windows 10. I am wondering if there is something wrong with my PC or is it just Ubuntu. The system specs are in the attached picture:
[image: system specs]

Here is the log of the last incident (could not provide the whole log till the shut down, as it would pass the characters limit):

```
Feb  4 14:59:55 d***7 systemd-timesyncd[1341]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.89.199:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Feb  4 15:00:15 d***7 systemd[1]: Starting Stop ureadahead data collection...
Feb  4 15:00:15 d***7 systemd[1]: Started Stop ureadahead data collection.
Feb  4 15:00:30 d***7 org.freedesktop.Notifications[1813]: org.kde.knotifications: WaitForName: Service was not registered within timeout
Feb  4 15:00:30 d***7 dbus-daemon[1813]: [session uid=121 pid=1813] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.Notifications' failed: Process org.freedesktop.Notifications exited with status 1
Feb  4 15:02:27 d***7 systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Feb  4 15:02:27 d***7 anacron[2354]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2020-02-04
Feb  4 15:02:27 d***7 anacron[2354]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Feb  4 15:05:01 d***7 CRON[2359]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1]: session-c1.scope: Killing process 1786 (lightdm) with signal SIGTERM.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1]: session-c1.scope: Killing process 1806 (lightdm-greeter) with signal SIGTERM.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1]: session-c1.scope: Killing process 1807 (unity-greeter) with signal SIGTERM.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1]: session-c1.scope: Killing process 1809 (at-spi-bus-laun) with signal SIGTERM.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1]: session-c1.scope: Killing process 1815 (dbus-daemon) with signal SIGTERM.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1]: session-c1.scope: Killing process 1817 (at-spi2-registr) with signal SIGTERM.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1]: session-c1.scope: Killing process 1844 (nm-applet) with signal SIGTERM.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1]: session-c1.scope: Killing process 1846 (unity-settings-) with signal SIGTERM.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1]: Stopping Session c1 of user lightdm.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 NetworkManager[1465]: <warn>  [1580857523.4988] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.open: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/1844/status”: No such file or directory
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 NetworkManager[1465]: <warn>  [1580857523.4993] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-network: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/1844/status”: No such file or directory
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 NetworkManager[1465]: <warn>  [1580857523.4999] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.sleep-wake: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/1844/status”: No such file or directory
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 NetworkManager[1465]: <warn>  [1580857523.5007] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wifi: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/1844/status”: No such file or directory
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 NetworkManager[1465]: <warn>  [1580857523.5014] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wwan: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/1844/status”: No such file or directory
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 NetworkManager[1465]: <warn>  [1580857523.5022] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wimax: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/1844/status”: No such file or directory
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 NetworkManager[1465]: <warn>  [1580857523.5025] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.network-control: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/1844/status”: No such file or directory
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 NetworkManager[1465]: <warn>  [1580857523.5030] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.protected: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/1844/status”: No such file or directory
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 NetworkManager[1465]: <warn>  [1580857523.5034] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.open: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/1844/status”: No such file or directory
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 NetworkManager[1465]: <warn>  [1580857523.5037] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.system: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/1844/status”: No such file or directory
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 NetworkManager[1465]: <warn>  [1580857523.5040] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.own: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/1844/status”: No such file or directory
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 NetworkManager[1465]: <warn>  [1580857523.5043] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.hostname: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/1844/status”: No such file or directory
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 NetworkManager[1465]: <warn>  [1580857523.5060] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.global-dns: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/1844/status”: No such file or directory
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 NetworkManager[1465]: <warn>  [1580857523.5062] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.reload: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/1844/status”: No such file or directory
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 NetworkManager[1465]: <warn>  [1580857523.5064] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.checkpoint-rollback: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/1844/status”: No such file or directory
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 NetworkManager[1465]: <warn>  [1580857523.5067] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-statistics: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/1844/status”: No such file or directory
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 NetworkManager[1465]: <warn>  [1580857523.5069] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-connectivity-check: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/1844/status”: No such file or directory
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of a***s.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 NetworkManager[1465]: <warn>  [1580857523.5075] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.protected: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/1844/status”: No such file or directory
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 NetworkManager[1465]: <warn>  [1580857523.5079] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.open: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/1844/status”: No such file or directory
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1001...
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1]: Started Session c2 of user a***s.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1]: Stopped Session c1 of user lightdm.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 121...
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1789]: Stopping Indicator Keyboard Backend...
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1789]: Stopping Indicator Sound Service...
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1789]: Stopping Indicator Date & Time Backend...
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1789]: Stopped target Default.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1789]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service...
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1789]: Stopping D-Bus User Message Bus...
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1789]: Stopping Indicator Power...
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1789]: Stopping Indicator Application Service...
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1789]: Stopping Indicator Session Service...
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1789]: Stopped Indicator Power.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1789]: Stopped Indicator Application Service.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1789]: Stopped Indicator Keyboard Backend.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1789]: Stopped Indicator Session Service.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1789]: Stopped D-Bus User Message Bus.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1789]: Stopped Indicator Date & Time Backend.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1789]: Stopped Indicator Sound Service.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[2366]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[2366]: Listening on GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[2366]: Starting D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[2366]: Started Pending report trigger for Ubuntu Report.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[2366]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[2366]: Listening on REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[2366]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[2366]: Reached target Timers.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[2366]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[2366]: Reached target Paths.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1789]: Stopped Virtual filesystem service.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1789]: Stopped target Basic System.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1789]: Stopped target Paths.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[2366]: Listening on D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[2366]: Reached target Sockets.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[2366]: Reached target Basic System.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[2366]: Reached target Default.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[2366]: Startup finished in 41ms.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1001.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1789]: Stopped Pending report trigger for Ubuntu Report.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1789]: Stopped target Sockets.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1789]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1789]: Closed D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1789]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1789]: Closed GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1789]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1789]: Closed REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1789]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1789]: Reached target Shutdown.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1789]: Starting Exit the Session...
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1789]: Stopped target Timers.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1789]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 2392 (kill).
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 121.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of lightdm.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[2366]: Started D-Bus User Message Bus.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 dbus-daemon[2446]: [session uid=1001 pid=2446] AppArmor D-Bus mediation is enabled
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 dbus-daemon[2446]: [session uid=1001 pid=2446] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.Daemon' unit='gvfs-daemon.service' requested by ':1.1' (uid=1001 pid=2437 comm="/usr/bin/ibus-daemon --daemonize --xim --address u" label="unconfined")
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[2366]: Starting Virtual filesystem service...
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 dbus-daemon[2446]: [session uid=1001 pid=2446] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.Daemon'
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 systemd[2366]: Started Virtual filesystem service.
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 dbus-daemon[2446]: [session uid=1001 pid=2446] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.portal.IBus' requested by ':1.1' (uid=1001 pid=2437 comm="/usr/bin/ibus-daemon --daemonize --xim --address u" label="unconfined")
Feb  4 15:05:23 d***7 dbus-daemon[2446]: [session uid=1001 pid=2446] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.portal.IBus'
Feb  4 15:05:24 d***7 gnome-session-c[2557]: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-KA0rU3t5eG: Connection refused
Feb  4 15:05:24 d***7 dbus-daemon[2446]: [session uid=1001 pid=2446] Activating service name='org.gnome.ScreenSaver' requested by ':1.23' (uid=1001 pid=2393 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-session/gnome-session-binary --sess" label="unconfined")
Feb  4 15:05:24 d***7 gnome-screensav[2564]: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-KA0rU3t5eG: Connection refused
Feb  4 15:05:24 d***7 gnome-screensav[2564]: Couldn't get presence status: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
Feb  4 15:05:24 d***7 dbus-daemon[2446]: [session uid=1001 pid=2446] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.ScreenSaver'
Feb  4 15:05:24 d***7 gnome-session[2393]: gnome-session-binary[2393]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file org.kde.kgpg.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary
Feb  4 15:05:24 d***7 gnome-session-binary[2393]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file org.kde.kgpg.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary
Feb  4 15:05:24 d***7 gnome-session[2393]: gnome-session-binary[2393]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file mpd.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary
Feb  4 15:05:24 d***7 gnome-session-binary[2393]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file mpd.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary
Feb  4 15:05:24 d***7 gnome-session[2393]: gnome-session-binary[2393]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file powerdevil.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary
Feb  4 15:05:24 d***7 gnome-session-binary[2393]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file powerdevil.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary
Feb  4 15:05:24 d***7 gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop[2570]: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1001/keyring/ssh
Feb  4 15:05:24 d***7 gnome-shell[2577]: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-KA0rU3t5eG: Connection refused
Feb  4 15:05:24 d***7 rtkit-daemon[1887]: Successfully made thread 2586 of process 2586 (n/a) owned by '1001' high priority at nice level -11.
Feb  4 15:05:26 d***7 rtkit-daemon[1887]: Successfully made thread 2587 of process 2586 (n/a) owned by '1001' RT at priority 5.
Feb  4 15:05:26 d***7 rtkit-daemon[1887]: Successfully made thread 2588 of process 2586 (n/a) owned by '1001' RT at priority 5.
Feb  4 15:05:26 d***7 dbus-daemon[1448]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service' requested by ':1.83' (uid=1001 pid=2586 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog " label="unconfined")
Feb  4 15:05:26 d***7 dbus-daemon[2446]: [session uid=1001 pid=2446] Activating service name='org.gnome.GConf' requested by ':1.30' (uid=1001 pid=2589 comm="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulse/gconf-helper " label="unconfined")
Feb  4 15:05:26 d***7 dbus-daemon[2446]: [session uid=1001 pid=2446] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.GConf'
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2577]: current session already has an ibus-daemon.
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 dbus-daemon[2446]: [session uid=1001 pid=2446] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.impl.portal.PermissionStore' unit='xdg-permission-store.service' requested by ':1.27' (uid=1001 pid=2577 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 systemd[2366]: Starting sandboxed app permission store...
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 dbus-daemon[2446]: [session uid=1001 pid=2446] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.impl.portal.PermissionStore'
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 systemd[2366]: Started sandboxed app permission store.
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 dbus-daemon[2446]: [session uid=1001 pid=2446] Activating service name='org.gnome.Shell.CalendarServer' requested by ':1.27' (uid=1001 pid=2577 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 dbus-daemon[2446]: [session uid=1001 pid=2446] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Sources5' unit='evolution-source-registry.service' requested by ':1.34' (uid=1001 pid=2618 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-calendar-server " label="unconfined")
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 systemd[2366]: Starting Evolution source registry...
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 dbus-daemon[2446]: [session uid=1001 pid=2446] Activating service name='org.gnome.OnlineAccounts' requested by ':1.35' (uid=1001 pid=2622 comm="/usr/lib/evolution/evolution-source-registry " label="unconfined")
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 dbus-daemon[2446]: [session uid=1001 pid=2446] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Sources5'
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 systemd[2366]: Started Evolution source registry.
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 dbus-daemon[2446]: [session uid=1001 pid=2446] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Shell.CalendarServer'
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 dbus-daemon[1448]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.GeoClue2' unit='geoclue.service' requested by ':1.79' (uid=1001 pid=2577 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 systemd[1]: Starting Location Lookup Service...
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 dbus-daemon[1448]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.bolt' unit='bolt.service' requested by ':1.79' (uid=1001 pid=2577 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 systemd[1]: Starting Thunderbolt system service...
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 dbus-daemon[2446]: [session uid=1001 pid=2446] Activating service name='ca.desrt.dconf' requested by ':1.27' (uid=1001 pid=2577 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 goa-daemon[2630]: goa-daemon version 3.28.0 starting
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 dbus-daemon[1448]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.GeoClue2'
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 systemd[1]: Started Location Lookup Service.
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 dbus-daemon[2446]: [session uid=1001 pid=2446] Successfully activated service 'ca.desrt.dconf'
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 dbus-daemon[2446]: [session uid=1001 pid=2446] Activating service name='org.gnome.Identity' requested by ':1.37' (uid=1001 pid=2630 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-online-accounts/goa-daemon " label="unconfined")
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 dbus-daemon[2446]: [session uid=1001 pid=2446] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.OnlineAccounts'
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 dbus-daemon[2446]: [session uid=1001 pid=2446] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Identity'
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 gnome-shell[2577]: Telepathy is not available, chat integration will be disabled.
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 dbus-daemon[2446]: [session uid=1001 pid=2446] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor' unit='gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor.service' requested by ':1.27' (uid=1001 pid=2577 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 systemd[2366]: Starting Virtual filesystem service - disk device monitor...
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 dbus-daemon[2446]: [session uid=1001 pid=2446] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor'
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 systemd[2366]: Started Virtual filesystem service - disk device monitor.
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 dbus-daemon[2446]: [session uid=1001 pid=2446] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.AfcVolumeMonitor' unit='gvfs-afc-volume-monitor.service' requested by ':1.27' (uid=1001 pid=2577 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 systemd[2366]: Starting Virtual filesystem service - Apple File Conduit monitor...
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 gvfs-afc-volume-monitor[2656]: Volume monitor alive
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 dbus-daemon[2446]: [session uid=1001 pid=2446] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.AfcVolumeMonitor'
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 systemd[2366]: Started Virtual filesystem service - Apple File Conduit monitor.
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 dbus-daemon[2446]: [session uid=1001 pid=2446] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor' unit='gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor.service' requested by ':1.27' (uid=1001 pid=2577 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 systemd[2366]: Starting Virtual filesystem service - digital camera monitor...
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 boltd[2635]: bolt 0.5 starting up.
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 boltd[2635]: config: loading user config
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 boltd[2635]: bouncer: initializing polkit
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 boltd[2635]: udev: initializing udev
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 boltd[2635]: store: loading devices
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 boltd[2635]: power: force power support: yes
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 boltd[2635]: power: setting force_power to ON
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 boltd[2635]: power: guard '1' for 'boltd' active
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 dbus-daemon[2446]: [session uid=1001 pid=2446] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor'
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 systemd[2366]: Started Virtual filesystem service - digital camera monitor.
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 dbus-daemon[2446]: [session uid=1001 pid=2446] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.GoaVolumeMonitor' unit='gvfs-goa-volume-monitor.service' requested by ':1.27' (uid=1001 pid=2577 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 systemd[2366]: Starting Virtual filesystem service - GNOME Online Accounts monitor...
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 dbus-daemon[2446]: [session uid=1001 pid=2446] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.GoaVolumeMonitor'
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 systemd[2366]: Started Virtual filesystem service - GNOME Online Accounts monitor.
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 dbus-daemon[2446]: [session uid=1001 pid=2446] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.MTPVolumeMonitor' unit='gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor.service' requested by ':1.27' (uid=1001 pid=2577 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 systemd[2366]: Starting Virtual filesystem service - Media Transfer Protocol monitor...
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 dbus-daemon[2446]: [session uid=1001 pid=2446] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.MTPVolumeMonitor'
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 systemd[2366]: Started Virtual filesystem service - Media Transfer Protocol monitor.
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 dbus-daemon[1448]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.PackageKit' unit='packagekit.service' requested by ':1.79' (uid=1001 pid=2577 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 systemd[1]: Starting PackageKit Daemon...
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 gsd-wacom[2677]: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-KA0rU3t5eG: Connection refused
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 gsd-xsettings[2679]: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-KA0rU3t5eG: Connection refused
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 gsd-clipboard[2684]: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-KA0rU3t5eG: Connection refused
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 gsd-color[2685]: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-KA0rU3t5eG: Connection refused
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 spice-vdagent[2709]: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 dbus-daemon[1448]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.PackageKit'
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 systemd[1]: Started PackageKit Daemon.
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 gsd-keyboard[2702]: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-KA0rU3t5eG: Connection refused
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop[2713]: dbus-daemon[2720]: Activating service name='org.a11y.atspi.Registry' requested by ':1.0' (uid=1001 pid=2700 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-media-keys " label="unconfined")
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop[2713]: dbus-daemon[2720]: Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop[2713]: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 gnome-session[2393]: gnome-session-binary[2393]: WARNING: App 'spice-vdagent.desktop' exited with code 1
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 gnome-session-binary[2393]: WARNING: App 'spice-vdagent.desktop' exited with code 1
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 dbus-daemon[1448]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.93' (uid=1001 pid=2727 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-rfkill " label="unconfined")
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 gsd-xsettings[2679]: Failed to get current display configuration state: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Name "org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig" does not exist
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 gnome-shell[2577]: JS WARNING: [/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/appIcons.js 1028]: unreachable code after return statement
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 dbus-daemon[1448]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.locale1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.locale1.service' requested by ':1.95' (uid=1001 pid=2702 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-keyboard " label="unconfined")
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 systemd[1]: Starting Locale Service...
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 gsd-sharing[2739]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-user-share-webdav.service not loaded.
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 gsd-sharing[2739]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit rygel.service not loaded.
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 gsd-sharing[2739]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-remote-desktop.service not loaded.
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 gnome-session-binary[2393]: Entering running state
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 at-spi2-registr[2731]: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.gnome.SessionManager.AlreadyRegistered: Unable to register client
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 at-spi2-registr[2731]: Unable to register client with session manager
Feb  4 15:05:27 d***7 gnome-shell[2577]: JS WARNING: [resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspaceThumbnail.js 891]: reference to undefined property "_switchWorkspaceNotifyId"
Feb  4 15:05:28 d***7 dbus-daemon[1448]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Feb  4 15:05:28 d***7 systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Feb  4 15:05:28 d***7 dbus-daemon[2446]: [session uid=1001 pid=2446] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.FileManager1' requested by ':1.65' (uid=1001 pid=2786 comm="nautilus-desktop " label="unconfined")
Feb  4 15:05:28 d***7 dbus-daemon[1448]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.locale1'
```

Comment: Do linux kernel SysRq keys work?  ie. can you safely shutdown via command to kernel (you didn't mention trying those, nor provide release details to know if it's enabled by default, or you need to enable it). Have you booted a 'live' media & checked your RAM, or done a *cap-check* on your box looking for reasons for unusual behavior.  (if *sysrq* keys don't work I'd not expect much in logs unless they are clues before the problem)

Comment: Edit your answer with your computer specs, make, model, and cpu. ram.  There are a few known bugs relating to ubuntu and hardware, most are easy to fix or have work arounds.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Comment: @guiverc No they do not work (I assume it is the same as prnt scr button, right?). It is Linux 4.15.0-76-generic (x86_64). I am a beginner. Would you please explain more on booting a live media to check RAM an doing a cap-check?

Comment: @karel Thank you, no it does not. My problem is not how to get out of a frozen state in Ubuntu. My question is whether the repeated occurrence of this is related to the OS or my hardware has problem.

Comment: Most of the time when Ubuntu freezes it is related to a hardware issue. In your case I think it's the GeForce GTX Titan X card.

Comment: Sysrq keys are caught and acted on by the kernel; ie. you use a combination to tell the kernel what you want it to do by-passing a locked desktop etc..  I assumed you'd use something like Alt+Sysrq (keeping ALT held down) then enter the commands REISUB (ie. those keys are pressed; each letter is a command).  Many of us don't remember all the commands, grab our phones & search online ('magic sysrq' is what I use, often wikipedia entry).

Comment: Depending on release there is a Memtest option on the 'live' media (install media). I booted the Xubuntu 18.04.4 besides me; hit a key when keyboard-icon-in-rectangle & person-in-circle appears for menu to appear, & select "Test Memory".  How this appears will be controlled by your hardware (ie. BIOS version/brand etc) and keystroke I mention may not be required. Some option exists for other flavors or Ubuntu itself.  Cap-check is not Ubuntu releated, but hardware - referring to opening case & visually sighting/touching the capacitors looking for swelling or signs of failure etc.

Comment: @guiverc Yes, I used Alt+PrntScr+REISUB. I will do the memory test and cap-check. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @karel What suggests you there is issue with the GPU?

Comment: The first paragraph of the body text of the question seems like the problem could be a hardware issue with the graphics card.

Comment: fyi:  If sysrq keys don't work, and no evidence of kernel panic (a reason for sysrq being ignored); it's usually hardware in my experience..

Answer (score 0):

You can delete and recreate ubuntu's swapfile. It's in the root.

Try these commands:

```
swapon --show
sudo swapoff -a /swapfile
sudo fallocate -l 4G /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
swapon --show
```

I am happy to report that ubuntu has not frozen once since I did this.